# ionic v1 instabug or other bug reporting service for a hybrid app

Tags: ionic-framework, instabug

so my friends and i are on the final weeks of development for our application. What we are looking for is a bug/issue reporting system that could take our users from our app to a webpage were they can report a bug. ideally it would be a service that we could hire that would allow us to track tickets and communicate with our users. thank you in advance for your help!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

We are using Sentry in all of our apps and it satisfies all of our needs completly. They offer a [client for angularjs](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/javascript/integrations/angularjs/) which will be the one you need with ionic v1. If you check out the [ionic developer servey](http://ionicframework.com/survey/2017#results) of 2017 you will find a nice graphic of which crash/error tracking tools are used most by ionic users:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instabug supports Ionic v1 apps (mobile only), you can find a link to the plugin here: https://github.com/Instabug/instabug-cordova

While it isn’t a webpage, it should serve what you’re looking for:

- Users can report a bug (with screenshot and logs)
- You can reply back to your users
- You and your team can use it to track and resolve tickets

If it’s a web app, you can check something like: https://usersnap.com.

Disclaimer: I work for Instabug